# Sorting Attachments Field in Sharepoint 2010 List

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

I have a custom SP  list with Attachments  fields and number of other fields in the List. 
After user upload many attachments in different stage user are facing difficulty of finding the latest file form the attachment field
As I notes attachment field was sorted in to alphabetical order !!! 
I like to know is there way to order this as created date ? 
Appreciate your suggestions (much appreciate OOB solution ) .

![enter image description here][1]
Cheers

Comment: Have you tried editing the view (or creating a new view) and telling it to sort by created date?